# How can I get an account ID from a username on Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos, user-accounts, macfuse

I'm using MacFUSE to create a cool filesystem. I'd like to set the `NSFileOwnerAccountID` and `NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID` attributes for the files on it, but the underlying framework I use only gives me user names.

How can I get an account ID from an account name under Mac OS X using Cocoa or other built-in frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just UID and GID numbers. Try the `getpwnam` (for user) and `getgrnam` (for group) functions; each returns a structure that contains the ID number, among other things.

Alternatively, just use `NSFileOwnerAccountName` and `NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName` instead of the `…AccountID` versions.

Comment: MacFuse _absolutely wants_ the `AccountID` versions.

Comment: @zneak: Dang. Well, those two functions should work for getting them.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get a list of all the [`CSIdentity` objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/IdentityServices_Ref/CSIdentity/CompositePage.html) and build a "username to identity" map.  Once you have the identity object, you can get a bunch of other information from it.

More info:

- [Identity Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/IdentityServices_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: The Collaboration framework (linked from the Identity Services Programming Guide) will probably be easier to use.